# ¿Para qué sirve el this en C# o para qué se usa?

Tags: c#, this

¿Por qué se usa el `this` en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)? Es mi primer lenguaje de programación pero no lo tengo muy claro.

¿Alguien me ayuda?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Como sugerencia, procura evitar el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas; se asimila a que gritas y creo que no es la idea :)  Lo otro: lo intentaste usar en algún código? Encontraste algún error raro? Procura ponerle contexto a la pregunta para que recibas respuestas más útiles.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda también, Robin, que la palabra reservada `this` no es exclusiva a C#. Muchos otros lenguajes de programación la utilizan.

Answer (score 3):

La **palabra clave this** **hace referencia a la** **instancia actual de la clase** y puede usarse para:

**Acceder a miembros ocultos por tener nombres similares**:

```
public class MiClase
{
    private int x;

    public void MiMetodo(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Al tener el **método MiMetodo** un parámetro con el mismo nombre de un miembro privado de la clase, usamos **this** para indicar que queremos acceder al miembro de la clase, de no usar **this** en este caso accederíamos al parámetro del método.

**También se usa para pasar un objeto como parámetro a otros métodos**:

```
public class MiClaseA
{
    public void MiMetodoA()
    {
        MiClaseB b = new MiClaseB();

        b.MiMetodoB(this);
    }
}

public class MiClaseB
{
    public void MiMetodoB(MiClaseA x)
    {
    }
}
```

La **clase MiClaseB** tiene un método que recibe como parámetro al tipo de datos **MiClaseA**, y al ser construido un objeto de tipo **MiClaseB** dentro de un método de **MiClaseA** podemos emplear **this** para indicar que el parámetro pasado al **método MiMetodoB**
se refiere al objeto actual de tipo **MiClaseA**.

**Otro uso de **this** sería la creación de métodos extensores**:

```
public static class Extensores
{
    public static int MiMetodoExtensor(this string x)
    {
    }
}
```

Para usar el método extensor haríamos:

```
var y = string.MiMetodoExtensor();
```

**Para saber más sobre métodos extensores vea**: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

**También puede usarse para construir indizadores**:

```
class MiIndizador
{
    private int[] vector;

    public MiIndizador
    {
        vector = new int[5];
    }

    public int this[int indice]
    {
        set
        {
             vector[indice] = value;
        }
        get
        {
             return vector[indice];
        }
    }
}
```

Para usar este indizador haríamos:

```
MiIndizador obj = new MiIndizador();
obj[0] = 7;
```

**Para saber más sobre indizadores vea**: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

**También puede usarse para invocar un constructor a partir de otro**:

```
public class  MiClase
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public MiClase(int p)
    {
        z = p;
    }

    public MiClase(int p, int q) : this(p + q) 
    {
        x = p;
        y = q;
    }
}
```

El segundo constructor de dos parámetros inicializa el objeto dándole valores a los **atributos x**, **y** e invoca al constructor de un parámetro para darle un valor al **atributo z** a partir de la suma de los **parámetros x**, **y**.

Un ejemplo de llamada sería:

```
MiClase obj = new MiClase(2, 5);
```

Los **atributos x**, **y** se inicializan con los valores **2** y **5** respectivamente, y el **atributo z** se inicializa como la suma de estos dos atributos, ahora **z** valdría **7**.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra reservada this hace referencia al objeto que estás usando en le momento en tu código, te paso un link dónde lo puedes [apreciar mejor](http://www.nachocabanes.com/csharp/curso2015/csharp07e.php)